# "setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8)" when connection to AWS EC2 servers with MacOS/iTerm2/ZSH

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2, ssh, locale, zsh

There are numerous related questions, but none of the answers solve this specific case:

I am on MacOS, using iTerm2 and ZSH.

Any AWS EC2 instance with the Amazon image (and maybe others) will show me that line when connecting to them with SSH:

> setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8)

The common answer to this problem seems to be a fix on the server. But this is not what I am looking for, I would like a fix on the client (since we create and destroy EC2 instances quite regularly).

I've tried to add this to my .zshrc file:

> export LC_CTYPE=UTF-8

ihinking that if it is already set to that locale, it won't complain. But that didn't work.

In iTerm2, there is an option:

[image]

I tried to disable that, but no change as well.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"UTF-8" looks like the name of a charset, not the name of a locale. That may be a valid locale on macOS but probably isn't on the EC2 servers. On a Linux system, you can list available locales with `locale -a`. Try values like `en_US.UTF-8` or perhaps `C.UTF-8`. If available, the latter is probably preferable.

It is probably better to set it from `.zprofile` rather than `.zshrc` and perhaps only conditionally if the existing value is "UTF-8":

```
    [[ $LC_CTYPE = UTF-8 ]] && LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8
```